# SecurityError when rendering textures in Three.js with phonegap/cordova on iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, three.js, wkwebview

I get a SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 when rendering textures in Three.js (gl.texImage2D.apply(gl,arguments) ) and the material appears black. I use phonegap 6.2.9 (cordova 6.1.1), Three.js (r78) on iOS WKWebView (platform version 4.1.1).

All worked fine as long as I build the app directly with a WKWebView component, based on [this project](http://www.agilityfeat.com/blog/2015/08/using-webgl-in-ios-without-phonegap-or-ionic).

After switching to phonagap I ran into this issue. I supposed it's caused by the Content-Security-Policy, but couldn't solve it this way. Taking images as base64 png is working, but I have multiple large images and the file size is not practical.

Now I fear it's the same issue as with [local XmlHttpRequests](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143).
But loading an image from an external Url also causes the SecurityError. And I can't follow, why there is a problem with phonegap/cordova and not with the naked WKWebView component (see above).

I have no idea furthermore and strongly need help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have found a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into CORS if you plan on serving the assets over http.

You need to set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header for your assets, see this wiki article for more info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Unfortunately I have to access to the assets locally.